# Do I need to worry about the airbag when replacing indicator switch?

Tags: nissan, safety, replace, pulsar

I'm about to replace the right indicator switch on my N15 Nissan Pulsar and have been looking up tutorials on how to achieve this. Seems simple enough but I read a comment about disconnecting the negative cable from the battery before proceeding as a caution for the airbag.

Do I need to worry about this and should I disconnect the negative as precaution?

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: It is always best to disconnect the battery when doing anything with the electrics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should absolutely disconnect the negative battery terminal. This is not just to prevent the air bag from deploying, you should always disconnect the battery before starting any work that involves the car's electrical system. This is because of safety, to prevent you from getting shocked (from the starter motor system) or burnt if you touch a live wire, and to prevent damage to the car's electrical system from an accidental short.

Comment: You can’t get a shock from 12 volts.  You could could short something and burn yourself or cause an electrical fire.

Comment: You can get a shock from the starter @HandyHowie, which wouldn't happen when working on the indicator, but could in other circumstances. I've edited that to make it clear.